# custom address scheme

Tags: pokadot

Can anyone help me please regarding the custom address scheme,

if i was to use a Custom address pallet, will this cause any complication with the existing EVM frontier pallet?

also are we able to have a custom address (which doesn’t start with 0x) and still have full functionality of EVM.?

If so, what is the best solution for doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.